# Recreating image from opaque pixels in another image

Tags: ios, core-graphics

My goal is to add an outline to all the opaque contents of the shield image here.

[image: Before]

I'm currently drawing the image in a separate context, iterating over each pixel to read the alpha value.

```
unsigned char * pixels = malloc((image.width * image.height));
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, image.size.width, image.size.height, 8, image.size.width, NULL, kCGImageAlphaOnly);
```

Once this is done I have an array of every CGPoint where an opaque pixel was. I then create a new image of the same size and paint every pixel red.

```
char * rgba = (char *)malloc(size.width * size.height * 4);
CGPoint pixelInQuestion = CGPointZero;
for (int i = 0; i < size.width * size.height; ++i)
{
    ...
    NSInteger locationOfOpaquePixel = [opaquePixels indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSValue *pointValue, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return (CGPointEqualToPoint(pixelInQuestion, [pointValue CGPointValue]));
    }];
    ...
}
```

[image: After]

I know that this must seem like an extremely inefficient technique (the time it takes to process even on my desktop machine proves that), and this is even without managing to add an outline yet.

Can anyone please recommend a better alternative to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand. I have a lot of experience processing images, and this should be instant

Comment: Right - if you paint the image to a context, have a new context for the new image, and read one pixel/one context. write the other context - should not be slow... @Jason so I agree with you.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's my approach that is the problem then. At the moment I iterate for each pixel in my new image, and in each iteration I query my array which contains all the points of opaque pixel coordinates. That is a rather large query that gets run a lot of times.

Comment: I've added the for loop I'm talking about in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a double loop over all your pixels: `indexOfObjectsPassingTest:` continues if you dont set `*stop` to `YES` after you have found your pixel. Maybe that's what's making it so slow?

My approach would be to add a shadow in one direction and draw and then add a shadow in the other direction and draw.

```
CGFloat width = image.size.width;
CGFloat height = image.size.height;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


// shadow in one direction
CGSize offset = CGSizeMake(2,2);
CGFloat blur = 0;
CGColorRef color = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, offset, blur, color);   
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image.CGImage);

// shadow in the other direction
CGSize offset2 = CGSizeMake(-2,-2);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor ( context, offset2, blur, color);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image.CGImage);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Another approach would be to draw the scaled image and blend it with a black filling and then draw the original image on top:

```
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(105, 20, 108, 159);
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
NSLog(@"imageView=%@", imageView);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapicon-1.png"];
[imageView setImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];


CGRect newImageFrame = CGRectInset(imageFrame, -20, -20);
CGRect newImageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, newImageFrame.size.width, newImageFrame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageFrame.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, newImageBounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextDrawImage(context, newImageBounds, image.CGImage);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, newImageBounds);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectInset(newImageBounds, 20, 20), image.CGImage);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 210, 108, 159)];
[newImageView setImage:newImage];
[self.view addSubview:newImageView];
```